# Autocomplete directive in Angular

Tags: angular, autocomplete, directive

Can someone please suggest a lightweight autocomplete (directive) in angular. Something apart from Material Autocomplete. Something with multi-select option would be ideal...

Comment: You can check https://ng-select.github.io/ng-select

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Thanks a lot, bud.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **@ng-select/ng-select**

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ng-select/ng-select

Comment: I'm relatively new to Angular and this was a great help. ng select looks good and just what I need. I'll reply again if I have any questions. Thanks a lot..